# How to test angular component with ag-grid

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an angular component which is using `ag-grid`. I created an empty test case which is failing with error `can not read property includes of undefined`.

Inside my component ts file I am using includes keyword only in once place. which is inside column definition `object`. below is that code.

```
cellClass: function (params) {
    return params.value.includes('Fail') ? 'status-fail' : null;
  }
```

Following is my unit test setup.

```js
 beforeEach(async(() => {  
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BannerComponent,CheckComponent,LinkComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule, 
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,  
        BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
        DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
        AgGridModule.withComponents([CheckComponent,LinkComponent])],
      providers: [
          { provide: BannerService, useClass: MockBannerService },         
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {paramMap:of(convertToParamMap({Id: 1}))} }
    ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));
  fit('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I am using mock service which is returning mock object list to display in grid. Inside `ngOnInit` method of component service is being called. mock list has all value for every property.

Not sure why params is undefined.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I have not worked with `ag-grid` , can u please add component and html code. I would be able to help u out once I get to see those code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how but removing fixture.detectchanges() from describe fixed my issue.